# Не работает регулярное выражение с "или"

Tags: javascript, json

У меня есть строка
`[{"text":"1","isDone":false},{"text":"2","isDone":false},{"text":"3","isDone":false}]`

Из которой надо удалить подстроку, номер которой `value` передается в функцию, то есть регулярное выражение должно учитывать, что подстрока может иметь либо true, либо false.
Например, для этой подстроки `{"text":"1","isDone":false}` `value = 1;`

Следовательно, результат должен быть:

`[,{"text":"2","isDone":false},{"text":"3","isDone":false}]`

Мои многочисленные попытки закончились на этом варианте кода:

```
let local = `[{"text":"${value}","isDone":false},{"text":"2","isDone":false},{"text":"3","isDone":false}]`

let reg = new RegExp(`{"text":"${taskValue}","isDone":true|false}`);

let a = local.replace(reg, '');
```

Кто может, помогите, пожалуйста, первый раз что-то делаю с регулярными выражениями и никак не могу понять, что не так

Comment: Но входящая строка JSON, зачем вы работаете с ней как со строкой, а не как с объектом?

Comment: Я бы даже сказал - массив объектов )

Comment: только что понял, что-то совсем глаз замылился:)

Answer (score 1):

Можно и через регулярку, но это некорректно:

```js
let taskValue = "2";
let local = `[{"text":"1","isDone":false},{"text":"2","isDone":false},{"text":"3","isDone":false}]`

let reg = new RegExp(`\{"text":"${taskValue}","isDone":(true|false)\}`);

let a = local.replace(reg, '').replace('[,', '[').replace(',,', ',').replace(',]', ']');

console.log(a);
```

А представленная строка это JSON, с массивом объектов:

```js
let taskValue = "2";
let local = `[{"text":"1","isDone":false},{"text":"2","isDone":false},{"text":"3","isDone":false}]`
let tempObj = JSON.parse(local);
let i = tempObj.findIndex(obj => obj.text === taskValue);
if (i !== -1) {
  tempObj.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(tempObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Наглупил и не увидел такого простого решения, спасибо!

```
let value = "1";
let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
const index = obj.findIndex(n => n.text === value);
if (index !== -1) {
  obj.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(obj);
```